# Create a column based on presence of dates within a specific range in multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe called df that looks similar to this (except the number of 'Visit' columns goes up to `Visit_74` and there are several hundred clients - I have simplified it here).

```
Client    Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4     Visit_5         
Client_1  2016-05-10  2016-05-25  2016-06-10  2016-06-25  2016-07-10
Client_2  2017-05-10  2017-05-25  2017-06-10  2017-06-25  2017-07-10
Client_3  2018-09-10  2018-09-26  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  
Client_4  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  2018-11-26  2018-12-10
```

I want to create a new column called `Four_Visits` with two values, `0` and `1`. I want to set `Four_Visits` to equal `1` if there are at least four dates in any one of the columns from `Visit_1` to `Visit_5` that fall between `2018-10-15` and `2018-12-15`. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Client    Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4     Visit_5     Four_Visits  
Client_1  2016-05-10  2016-05-25  2016-06-10  2016-06-25  2016-07-10  0
Client_2  2017-05-10  2017-05-25  2017-06-10  2017-06-25  2017-07-10  0
Client_3  2018-09-10  2018-09-26  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  0
Client_4  2018-10-10  2018-10-26  2018-11-10  2018-11-26  2018-12-10  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `datetime` if not already, then use filter and `>=` + `<=` to check if more than 4 visit columns fall between the dates for each row:

```
import pandas as pd
# df = df.set_index('Client').apply(pd.to_datetime).reset_index()

df['Four_Visits'] = ((df.filter(like='Visit').ge(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')).fillna(0).astype(bool))
                     & (df.filter(like='Visit').le(pd.to_datetime('2018-12-15')).fillna(0).astype(bool))
                    ).sum(1).ge(4).astype('int')
```

#### Output:

```
     Client    Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Visit_4    Visit_5  Four_Visits
0  Client_1 2016-05-10 2016-05-25 2016-06-10 2016-06-25 2016-07-10            0
1  Client_2 2017-05-10 2017-05-25 2017-06-10 2017-06-25 2017-07-10            0
2  Client_3 2018-09-10 2018-09-26 2018-10-10 2018-10-26 2018-11-10            0
3  Client_4 2018-10-10 2018-10-26 2018-11-10 2018-11-26 2018-12-10            1
```

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like its exactly what I need, but when I try and use it in the original df with 73 Visit columns and 296 Clients, I get the following error message: `ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`. Why am I getting this? Everything is converted to datetime. Some of the columns have missing data as clients have had different numbers of visits - could that be the issue?

Comment: I wasn't able to run the code, despite the extra parentheses. However, I was able to run it after running the following code before running your code above:

`df = df.fillna(pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01'))`

So it seems the issue was the missing data. Is there a better way I can do this e.g. a way I can get your code above to skip missing data rather than be broken by it?

Comment: @FGreen see my update. There appears to be an issue when comparing an entire DataFrame with `NaT` values. the addition of `.fillna(0).astype(bool)` will make it work without first replacing the NaT values.

Comment: That works perfectly - thanks @ALollz. Can I ask though, what role does the 0 in .fillna(0) play? And what about the 1 in sum(1)? Thanks again

Comment: @FGreen See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046100/how-to-properly-handle-datetime-comparisons-in-an-entire-dataframe-with-nat-valu) I just asked. It seems that when you use `.ge` it isn't handling the `NaT` properly and returns a `float` column with `NaN` for every comparison with `NaT`. The standard logic is that any `== < > <= >=` comparison with a null should return `False`, which is why I fill those with 0 and then cast to bool as `bool(0) == False`, But really good question, this made me learn a lot!

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the follow-up. And what about the 1 in sum(1), is that to designate the axis?

Comment: @FGreen yes. Specified to sum across rows