# How to properly handle datetime comparisons in an entire DataFrame with NaT values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I stumbled upon this odd behavior when trying to check if a `DataFrame` has values above a certain date, while that DataFrame may also contain `pd.NaT`

Comparisons of values behaves as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.NaT > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
# False
```

Comparisons with a `Series` also behave as expected:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.NaT, pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16')])
s > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')

#0    False
#1     True
#dtype: bool
```

But the `DataFrame` comparison isn't correct:

```
s.to_frame() > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
#      0
#0  True
#1  True
```

It seems to me the issue is that the comparison initially returns `NaN` which is (at some point?) coerced to `True` given the behavior of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.NaT, pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16')],
                   [pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16'), pd.NaT]])

df >= pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
#      0     1
#0  True  True
#1  True  True

df.ge(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15'))
#     0    1
#0  NaN  1.0
#1  1.0  NaN
```

So can we really not use the `> < >= <=` operators when comparing for a `DataFrame` and need to rely on `.lt .gt .le .ge` followed by a `.fillna(0)`?

```
df.ge(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')).fillna(0)
#     0    1
#0  0.0  1.0
#1  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: s.apply(lambda x: x > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')

Comment: Yes, that does get the job done and is concise, though is slow compared to `df.ge(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')).fillna(0).astype(bool)`

Comment: It might be worth digging deeper here; this sounds like a bug to me. If `NaN` is always `False` when compared, shouldn't `NaT` behave the same?

Comment: This behaviour is not displayed when building a series with a `NaN` entry. E.g. run `pd.Series([np.nan, 3]).to_frame() > 2`

Comment: I'm really curious what causes this behavior.

Comment: Here's a big hint I think.   The '>' function __div__ in pandas core, I think, converts the arguments values to np.float64.  Note: the difference in `s.to_frame() > pd.datetime('2018-10-15')` and `s.to_frame() < pd.datetime('2018-10-15')`.

Comment: @ScottBoston: yes, I suspect this bug came about due to some unintended numeric conversion.  Timestamps are backed by integers in pandas, so for efficiency an integer value was also chosen represent `NaT` (so Series with nulls and the like can be backed by a single dtyped numpy array and stored as a contiguous block of memory).  From an implementation standpoint, it makes sense to choose this integer value at one of the far ends of the spectrum, and for pandas this was choosen to be the smallest possible value (see `pd.NaT.value` vs. `pd.Timestamp.min.value`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug that will be fixed in the next release of pandas (0.24.0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.0.dev0+1504.g9642fea9c'

In [2]: s = pd.Series([pd.NaT, pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16')])

In [3]: s > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
Out[3]:
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

In [4]: s.to_frame() > pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
Out[4]:
       0
0  False
1   True

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.NaT, pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16')],
   ...:                    [pd.to_datetime('2018-10-16'), pd.NaT]])
   ...:

In [6]: df >= pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15')
Out[6]:
       0      1
0  False   True
1   True  False

In [7]: df.ge(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-15'))
Out[7]:
       0      1
0  False   True
1   True  False
```

For the corresponding GitHub issue, see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22242